# Build RPM file in another name than tar source

Tags: build, rpm

Is there a way to build any RPM file in another name than tar source.
I've currently a tar file, like this:

**my-current-file.10.1-cert1.tar.gz** and I'd like to get a result like this: **my-file-certified-10.1.1-1.rpm**

Do you think it's possible in the **spec** file or the rpm file will be on the same format anyway?

Answer (score 1):

It is as simple as:

```
Name: my-file-certified
Version: 10.1.1
Source0: my-current-file.10.1-cert1.tar.gz
```